# Warning: nvcc path != CUDA_PATH while installing chainer with sudo CUDA_PATH

Tags: python, linux, chainer

I was running a code in [orenmel](https://github.com/orenmel/context2vec.It), it is cool with CPU. But when I ran -train_context2vec.py- with GPU, I recieved：

> Warning: nvcc path != CUDA_PATH
>   ...
>   cuda.check_cuda_available() 
>   RuntimeError: CUDA environment is not correctly set up, cannot import name core

So I did this: [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9S4Ey.png)

Then I used this `sudo CUDA_PATH=/usr/local/cuda-8.0 pip install chainer`. It said:

> error: command "x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc" failed with exit status 1".

If the CUDA_PATH is set somewhere else.Or I just use sudo pip install chainer.It can be installed.
Others can use the gpu in Keras and theano.

Answer (score 0):

This was solved by uninstalling theano.